# Error Sql (1064) creating a function in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, functions, syntax

I am getting an error in MariaDB when trying to create a function. It gives me the following error and I leave the script below.

[image]

The script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `total_hh`(fechainicio  datetime, fechafin datetime) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
RETURN (select count(*) from datos d where d.fecha between date_format(fechainicio, "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i") and date_format(fechafin,"%Y,%m,%d %H,%i")
);
  END
```

ACTUALIZATION:
Now im getting this error when i try to create the function. Else when i try to run the script like a query i have another error SQL (1558).

[image]

Comment: You create your function using some third-party client software. Read its help about "What is correct way to create stored objects".

Comment: Ok, sorry im new in Stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your query:

- your `SET` statements do not end with a semicolon (main cause of your fired error)
- your function has no `RETURN` clause

Additionally, you should use the space reserved for input values with the variables you declare inside your function.

You can try using the following syntax:

```
CREATE FUNCTION total_hh(
    fechainicio DATETIME,
    fechafin    DATETIME
) 
RETURNS INT(11)
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM datos as d 
        WHERE d.fecha BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(fechainicio, "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i") 
                          AND DATE_FORMAT(fechafin   , "%Y,%m,%d %H,%i"));
```

This compact form avoids you to change delimiters too.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2MMrT4FA).

**Note**: A function is defined by a header and a body. The workbench allows you to help with the definition of the header with the form. Inside the body section (cuerpo de la rutina) you need to add **only** the body (`RETURN (SELECT ... );`).

Comment: Hi lemon and thanks for your response. Now im getting this,

ERROR DE SQL (1303): Cant create a function from within another stored routine.

This if i put it like Function do not return a result. However, if i put function thats returns a result (int) i recibe ERROR SQL (1303) at line 8.

Comment: This description of the error tells you what the issue is: "*Cant create a function from within another stored routine*", you should do it outside of any routine.

Comment: I've added a demo at the bottom of the answer for you to see how it is expected to work. @EduardoEstayAtenas

Comment: I am very grateful for your kindness Lemon. Sorry to bother you so much, but now I get SQL error (1558): Column count of mysql.proc is wrong (expected 21, found 20). I followed your steps creating the data table first and then when creating the function it throws me this error. I am really very frustrated.

Comment: Check the note on the updated answer.